# jQuery Validation dependency

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

How do I go about validating a password based on a valid email address that has been provided?

Here's my setup:

```
    $("#login-form").validate( { 
    rules: {
        email: {
            required:true,
            email:true,
            remote:"check_email.php" 
        },
        password: {
            required:true,
        }
    }, 
    messages: {
        email: {
            required:"Please enter an email address.",
            email:"Invalid email.",
            remote:"Incorrect email."
        },
        password: {
            required:"Please enter a password.",
        }
    }
 });
```

I can validate an email address easy enough by passing it to a PHP script and query the database, but how can I ensure that even though the email is valid, the corresponding password may not?

Any help here would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to check them both on the server on form submission, not as client-side validation.

Answer (score 0):

what I will do is, run de validation using the current rules that you have, and instead using a submit button I ll use a regular button `<button type="button" onClick="submitFunction()">Submit</button>`  and if all are valid then validate the password, i don't know what exactly are you trying to validate, but heres a small example:

```
function submitFunction(){
  var $form = $('form');
  $form.validate({(here goes all your rules)});
  if (!$form.valid){
    return;
  }
  // here you can do your password validation or other validations on the client side
  $.ajax({
    uri: 'myServerSideValidatorOrSubmitUrl.php',
    type: 'POST'  
    data: $form.serializeArray(),
    success: function(data) {
      // if this ajax is for server side validation then submit the form,     
      $form.submit();
      // otherwise show form response
      alert('all OK');
    }
  }) 
}
```

I haven't test this code but this is the basic idea.